# Invalid redirect_URI Web AppBuilder Deployment from Server?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have configured an ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Map as an application in ArcGIS Online.  It is consumed by IIS6 on a Windows 2003 Server Machine.  When I hit the URL; I receive ERROR 400 Invalid URI_indirect.  My application was copied to my server from AGOL. What is the solution for this if I am not using Web AppBuilder in Development mode?  What should my URI be when I register the app in AGOL

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the `appid` that you're using does not have your new URL in its list of Redirect URIs. Here are the instructions from the Web AppBuilder FAQs:

> It is indicated that the URI of Web AppBuilder is not added or set correctly in the Redirect URI list when you registered the App ID for Web AppBuilder in the ArcGIS portal. Complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Go to `/server` directory of the Web AppBuilder installation, delete signininfo.json file.
> 2. Review step 4. Update the existing App ID with the correct redirect URIs. see [View and update app registration info](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/add-items.htm). Alternatively, you can create a new App ID from the scratch.
> 3. Refresh the browser running Web AppBuilder. Provide your App ID again, and click `Continue`.

https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/faqs.htm

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this issue multiple times and i was able to solve this issue by doing couple of things.

1. Unregister your portal application and then delete signininfo.json
   file from "...\WebAppBuilderForArcGIS\server" directory. If you are
   not sure where to find this file go to web AppBuilder install
   directory and follow the above path.
2. Re-create the application your portal for ArcGIS.
3. While Generating application id(APPID) make sure you enter all possible

combination of local urls. Please see attached screen shot for [image: img-link]
This should solve your problem, however in some cases you might need to delete your Web AppBuilder folder and then unzip from original zip file, some cases renaming of parent folder also work.
Also Don't forget to allow node.js to open ports in your local firewall, as without that your firewall can not communicate with webappbuilder and your web appbuilder will not work.

Comment: Entering all possible combos of URLs worked for me when nothing else seemed to have.